# Error getting the URL of a specific post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a PHP line:

```
echo "<a href='".the_permalink(get_the_id())."'>".get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), array(150,120))."</a>";
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show an image pointing to its post where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're concatenating the string, try [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) instead of the_permalink.